# Pointer to member for std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, emscripten, stdarray

Suppose I have a structure containing an array of objects of another structure type, like this:

```
struct foo { int x, y; };
struct bar { std::array<foo, 4> foos; };
```

Is it possible to portably write an expression which will evaluate to a pointer-to-member for a given attribute of a given array element? Something like `&bar::foos[2]::x`?

The application is [embind](https://github.com/imvu/emscripten/wiki/embind): I'd like to map a nested C++ type like this to a linear JavaScript tuple if possible. If this does not work out using pointer-to-member, then I could probably try using getter and setter methods instead, but I would still like to know whether there is a way to obtain such a pointer-to-member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do anything like that. `foos[2]` is not a member of `bar`, only `foos` is. You cannot get a pointer-to-member from something which is not a member. Paragraph 5.3.1/4 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit `&` is used and its operand is a *qualified-id* not enclosed in parentheses.

This means the grammar itself prevents you from writing anything that does not look like:

```
&class_name::member_name
```

where `class_name` could itself be a qualified name. No subscript operator or other fancy notation is allowed.

Comment: OK, so the intuitive pointer-to-member expression is not valid. But does that say that I can't obtain a `int foo::*` using some other clever means? Like some pointer arithmetic to combine the individual offsets, or some `offsetof` thingy, or something like that? After all, all of these have known type and offset, so it does seem technically possible.

Comment: @MvG: Hum, but what would you do with that `int`? AFAIK the representation of pointer-to-members is unspecified, so I do not think your code would be portable. And even if it were specified, you would not end up with a pointer-to-member anyway, since `foos[2]` is not a member of `A`. You won't be able to do something like `a.*pF2 = 42`.

Comment: I would have hoped for some `int foo::*ptm` such that `a.*ptm = 42` would be equivalent to `a.foos[2].y = 42`. Which in turn would be equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<int*>(&a)[2*2 + 1] = 42`.

Comment: @MvG: I'm afraid that's just impossible in C++